# binding a click event to jqzoom to launch fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jqzoom

So I've been playing around with this for a while, but cannot get the binded click event to fire  from a jqzoomed element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product-clicktozoom-image">
    <div class="product-clicktozoom-image-main">
        <a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" class="jqzoom" title="Image" rel="gall"><img itemprop="image" id="mainimage" src="http://exampe.com/image.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image"/></a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).load(function() {
    jQuery('#mainimage').bind('click',function(){
            var fancyImage = jQuery('#mainimage').attr('src');              
            jQuery.fancybox.open(fancyImage); 
    });
});
```

jqzoom creates a couple of extra div's so the final page structure actually looks like this:

```
<div class="product-clicktozoom-image-main">
    <a href="example.com/image.jpg" class="jqzoom" title="" rel="gall" style="outline-style: none; text-decoration: none;">
        <div class="zoomPad">
            <img itemprop="image" id="mainimage" src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image" style="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="zoomPup" style="display: none; top: 105px; left: 145px; width: 126px; height: 126px; position: absolute; border-width: 1px;"></div>
                <div class="zoomWindow" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5001; cursor: default; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
                    <div class="zoomWrapper" style="border-width: 1px; width: 355px; cursor: crosshair;">
                        <div class="zoomWrapperTitle" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
                        <div class="zoomWrapperImage" style="width: 100%; height: 355px;">
                            <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" style="position: absolute; border: 0px; display: block; left: -411.26760563380276px; top: -298.5915492957746px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="zoomPreload" style="visibility: hidden; top: 156px; left: 132.5px; position: absolute;">Loading zoom</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have tried binding the click event to the #mainimage, along with the zoomPad class and also the img within the zoomWrapperImage element as this appears to be the top element when you mouseover the image.

All I want to do is open the full image in a fancybox if they click on the zoom (currently the zoom happens on mouseover). I know the fancybox.open(fancyImage); works, I can run the code in the click function directly in the console successfully, I just can't get it to fire from the click event itself.

Help!

Comment: You'll likely have to create a jsFiddle if you want help with this, very plugin-specific, question. [Here's a fiddle pre-configured with fancybox and jqzoom](http://jsfiddle.net/TBfZ4/) to get you started. Customize as you wish and `Update`, then edit your question and post the URL for others. Note the External Resources accordion -- that's where you specify the CDNs for the additional js (note: no http: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple in the end, the click event needs to bind on the .zoomPad, and I used window.load in place of (document).ready as that ensures all the elements have loaded.

**Final JS:**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.zoomPad').bind('click',function(){
            var fancyImage = jQuery('.zoomWrapperImage img').attr('src');      
            jQuery.fancybox.open([{href : fancyImage}], {closeClick : true}); 
    });
});
```